# How can i update my jLabel through another Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety, jlabel

So, I have made a socket connection which runs on another thread. Now I want to update the number of connections each time a connection is accepted. But a change in a public variable is reflected but not in the GUI of the label. Here is a piece of my code:

```
while(flag){
    try{
        s = ss2.accept();
        ob.inc();
        System.out.print(ob.counter.getText());
        String x = ob.counter.getText();
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println("connection Established");

    }

catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Connection Error");

}
```

}
    }

The code in the GUI section is:

```
public void inc()
{
    ctr++;
       counter.setText(String.valueOf(ctr));
    counter.repaint();
}
```

Can anyone tell how I can dynamically change the jLabel values?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If `inc()` is called from a worker thread (not the main or UI thread) then you would want to wrap that call inside of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Comment: Thank You for your response! I tried that already yet it didn't work. The GUI is not updating until an event has occurred. Do you have possibly any other way wherein the GUI would get updated?

Comment: Try to simplify your program to the minimum required to reproduce the issue. For example, forget about the socket and just use a plain worker thread to increment a counter, sleeping 1 second between updates. Can you update the UI now? If so, then there is a problem with the other part of your program. If not, there is something fundamentally incorrect about your UI code. I haven't used Swing in years so I can't give you specific advice, but that is how I would approach it. Continue to pare things down until you can update the UI, then build it back up. Good luck!